# Memcache - How to prevent frequent cache rebuilds?

Tags: php, mysqli, memcached

I have been working for Memcache for the last week or so, I have managed to work out how to set keys/delete keys. This is fine but Im still attempting to work out how to do the same for a while loop of results.

For example I will have a while loop of posts, from within the logic the function will check to see if Memcache is set, if not it will collect the results and create the key. My question is this, **If I have set the looped data into a set key and display the set key (Newest First) Then what happens when a new post is inserted?** I understand I can set a time limit on the set key, but as the content will/could be added whenever it seems that setting a limit could still display old posts. So my question is how would I be able to update the set key.

The only way I can think of a possible solution is for when a user inserts a new post, this deletes the key, and when the all posts is viewed again this is when the key gets set again. But this seems rather counter productive, just as if there are 10's of users submitting posts then all the posts will be set over and over again (Doesn't really seem beneficial)

I hope this makes sense, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the scenario you specified will happen if you delete the key when there's a new post. To escape that you can use a) memcache's expiration or b) maintain own job system controlling the threshold of cache rebuild.

**Memcache's Expiration**

PHP has two Memecache PECL plugins i.e. [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php). Memcached (note the d suffix) supports a method called [touch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.touch.php) which allows us to set a new expiration time for an existing item. Assuming that you set your cache for 2 hours, when a new post appears, we can set the expiration to 10 minutes using `touch`. Thus if there are new posts within the next 10 minutes, the cache will be rebuilt only once. This technique is known as debouncing in technical terms.

Some code:

```
$_memcached = new Memcached;
if(!$_memcached->addServer('localhost',11211))
{
    $_isConnected = FALSE;
}
else
{
    $_isConnected = TRUE;
}

$_memcached->touch($key, $expiry);

$_memcaced->add($key, $value, $expiry);
```

Please note: this is for example only, please create a singleton class and use this.

If you have to use the old Memcache plugin, then you can only replicate the behaviour of `touch` using a combination of (atomic) `get` and `set`.

**Job system**

If you have a job system then submit a job every time a new post appears which will be executed by a job aggregator to control the frequency of cache rebuilds.

Going with Memecached seems like the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Birla thats helpful. I have installed Memcached, which seems the better of the two (albeit the vast majority of articles I have read are primarily aimed at Memcache) Would you be able to give a crude example of using the touch method (or know any examples online?) I will try and update my question with some code to illustrate how I coulr/may tackle this problem. In regards to the touch method.

Comment: @LeeMarshall I have updated the answer with some code. Basically you need to call `touch` on the same key as when you call `add` for storing the group of latest posts.

Comment: I see what you mean, am I right in saying the touch method wont allow another rebuild until the touch method expiration has occurred? Is this right? Preventing lots of rebuilds in a given period of time (In the above example that would be 10mins)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Another way to look at it is that there will be at least a 10 minute delay before a new post appears in the cached data. The best way to solve your problem would actually be to throttle not debounce, but we cannot use memcache alone to achieve that. See http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation for a comparison between debouncing and throttling, although in context of JavaScript it should help..